# react-native-qrcode-scanner building error

Tags: react-native, qr-code

**Why I am getting this error when "./gradlew assembleRelease", releasing ?**

'E:\New' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Task :app:bundleReleaseJsAndAssets FAILED

FAILURE: Build completed with 2 failures.

### 1: Task failed with an exception.

Where:
Script 'E:\New folder (2)\qr\node_modules\react-native\react.gradle' line: 286

What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:bundleReleaseJsAndAssets'.
Process 'command 'cmd'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

## Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
Run with --scan to get full insights.

### 2: Task failed with an exception.

What went wrong:
java.lang.StackOverflowError (no error message)

## Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
Run with --scan to get full insights.

Get more help at https://help.gradle.org/

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 8.0.

You can use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings and determine if they come from your own scripts or plugins.

See https://docs.gradle.org/7.5.1/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

Execution optimizations have been disabled for 1 invalid unit(s) of work during this build to ensure correctness.
Please consult deprecation warnings for more details.

BUILD FAILED in 50s
40 actionable tasks: 35 executed, 5 up-to-date
PS E:\New folder (2)\qr\android>
Gradle
Gradle | Search for Help with Gradle Build Tool
Image
Why I am getting this error when "./gradlew assembleRelease", releasing ?
Bro please help

I tried "./gradlew assembleRelease", It shows this error , and when I run npx react-native run-android it is building perfectly but when I comes for final release then It get error .. what to do ???